# Dummy-variable depending on character lengths of df$id column

Tags: r, string-length, dummy-variable

I am trying to create an id dummy in r. The situation is a little bit tricky. I want to set id1=1 if the length of id = 15, and 0 if the length =11(that's the only two cases). 
I tried the following code:

```
id1 <- ifelse(nchar(as.character(data$id) == "15"), 1,0)
```

the code can run but when I look at the data I found all the value generated is 1 rather than 0,1. In other words I doubt that something goes wrong with the setting of the ifelse function.

I also tried this:

```
id1 <- factor(ifelse(nchar(as.character(data$id) == "15"), 1,0))
```

still got the same result.

Can anyone help me about this please?

The data are like this:

```
id
799679d656c
032a71ce6132f38
b89602494f78508
c817fdde8fd
74e69d6b574
37d4c1ad5e56d06
63d89a0171f
c8bdb87cd537472
bdc09ee5421b1ec
967f47694e6
e4d825005b1
0eb6b851bba
9b27fa6949aaa42
bc82516f141
c4c7f10be01
cb90e05f8a4
cb45e5a890e
a93f57b965d78eb
5e3bb4f29457d75
62aa2cb20a30e07
33e8f2cd8bd
fdecbac8b827917
b51ea777c53d720
```

Comment: mabybe its a misplaced bracket .. `ifelse(nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15, 1,0)`

Comment: For this, you don't need `ifelse` `as.integer(nchar(as.character(df1$id))=='15')`

Comment: Or even more code golfing `+(nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15)`

Comment: @user20650 there is no "maybe" here :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg; ... ha, true .. my typical scottish reserve

Comment: @user20650 is it possibly Scottish sarcasm?  I'm quite a few generations removed from actual Scottish ancestry but I know I'm sarcastic as hell.

Comment: I created tag [tag:dummy-variable] and applied it. Can't believe it didn't exist before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the explicit `ifelse` statement:

```
id1 <- (nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15)+0L
```

This works because thanks to the brevity of R code, the comparison operator `==` tests the equality of the two sides without using if, or else. The if statement is implied in the test, replacing a potentially verbose programming task to one concisely executed in R. (credit @DavidArenburg for the zero addition)

The direct fix to your code as mentioned in the comments from user20650:

```
id1 <- ifelse(nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15, 1,0)
```

**Results**

```
id1
 #[1] 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this one but got the following error:Error in nchar(data$id) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Comment: the parameter `stringsAsFactors` should be set to FALSE when creating the data frame.

Comment: If you are unable to do that this works also `data$id <- as.character(data$id)`

Comment: Hi, I did this: id1 <- as.character(data$id), then this id2 <- as.numeric(nchar(id1) == 15)
Still the value generated for id2 are all 0s rather than 0,1.

Comment: You do realize this was provided in comments long ago, right? In this case `as.integer` is preferable both by speed and memory. Or just `+` which is also less typing and even faster.

Comment: I posted because of the numeric coercion approach. I did not add the answer from the comments at first to give the commenter an opportunity to post an answer. I just added it with mention.

Comment: I mean I want to set ID=1 if the lengths of id = 15, otherwise set ID = 0.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is no matter I try numeric or character, the values generated for ID are always just 0s, acting as if the code setting is unable to count the lengths correctly.

Comment: All we have to go on is the examples that you provide. The solution I provided, and the one I noted from the comments both work for me.

Comment: Hi I tried both ways in the updated answer. Still, just 0s are generated for all observations. Acting as if the system can't tell 15 from 11 but just treat them all like "else" situation.

Comment: Ok. can you post the first five examples that you used. and post the ouput also?

Comment: So with id1 <- ifelse(nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15, 1,0), did you actually see 0 and 1 in the data? cause in my case I only got 0s. I am not sure if it has anything to do with the size of the data set. My actual data set has thousands of observations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81805/discussion-between-plafort-and-cat88).

Comment: ID <- as.integer(nchar(as.character(data$id))=='15')
ID <- ifelse(nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15, 1,0)
ID <- (nchar(as.character(data$id)) == 15)+0L                 I tried these. And in each cases I got the same result when I list(ID), it's like this                        [89461] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[89497] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[89533] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0